# Can I clone/restore UEFI disk image on Legacy machine, and boot the cloned/restored disk later from UEFI machine? Acronis True Image

Tags: boot, uefi, clone, acronis-trueimage

I'm currenly at home and I'd like to restore a UEFI disk image (full disk backup, using acronis) to another disk, and keep it UEFI, although I am booting Acronis TrueImage from Legacy machine. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your full disk image contains all relevant partitions including EFI System Partition this is possible.

In the [Acronis True Image 2019 Userguide](https://dl.acronis.com/u/pdf/ATI2019_userguide_en-US.pdf) on page 94 you will find a table titled *Partition style after recovery* outlining all possible combinations of booting Bios or UEFI and restoring GPT or MBR partitions.

Your case is:

> My system is BIOS-booted
>   My source disk is GPT
>   After operation completion, the partition style will remain GPT

To sum this up: by booting into UEFI you could convert MBR to GPT while on legacy systems you can handle GPT partitions without limitations and prepare disks for other systems.

The only limitations listed in the manual concern some aspects of dynamic disks.