# How to normalise Win10 MBR partition to migrate to GPT and standard EFI

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, mbr, gpt, efi

My aim is to be able to upgrade to Windows 11.

It was originally a Windows XP installation, that went through all the upgrades to WinVista, Win7, Win8, Win8.1 and Win10. With my upgrade path I never had a separate partition (usually 50 or 100MiB big I think).
So currently I have on my SSD 3 primary partitions on a normal MBR partition table. The C partition marked as active (boot), the invisible WinRE partition (msftres) and a normal partition for games.
Despite MBR partition everything booted up with UEFI without legacy mode on.

`mbr2gpt /validate` doesn't work and says `Disk layout validation failed for disk 1`.

`bootrec /rebuildbcd` finds the Windows 10 installation but quits with `The requested system device cannot be found.`

If I just convert MBR to GPT with <strike>AOMEI Partition Assistant</strike> DiskGenius included in current Hiren's Boot CD while keeping the partitions as the are, Windows becomes unbootable. By converting it back to MBR and restoring the active/boot flag, Windows boots again correctly. Funny enough without active/boot it still boots fine but I can't shutdown it and `shutdown.exe` tells something about system device not found.

I want to keep and fix the current installation with all configuration and installed programs without reinstalling and/or complete re-partitioning. But I'm out of ideas and knowledge. Possible thought: I have to set some flags on partitions after converting partition table to GPT to make it bootable, but what would those flags be?

Edit: Added layout as picture.
[Layout of the SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWzmd.png)

C has following flags according to Windows: System, Starting partition, Swap file, Active, Crash dumps, Primary partition

Edit2: The solution of user1686 worked perfectly. As additional measure I had to clean EFI folder on drive C (which didn't work/boot correctly) and somehow also a new EFI folder, that appeared on WinRE partition. Everything boots now perfectly and at this moment Windows 11 is installing itself and is now at 73%.

Comment: It might help to post a screenshot of your current layout so people can see what might be causing a problem.

Comment: I aded the screenshot as link and translated info of drive C from the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the boot partition manually, format it, populate it using `bcdboot`.

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI
```

Some official Microsoft guides on manual partitioning:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11

For EFI the boot partition can be at any position; for BIOS it has to be entirely within the first 2 TiB. You could probably repurpose the 450 MB "recovery" partition, or you could create space by shrinking some other partition.

(Though I would probably take the time to create a "clean" layout: shrink the C:\ partition to minimum (to make the next step faster), use GParted to *move* it some ~200 MB to the right (making space for a new boot partition before it), grow it back to full size, and create the boot partition at the very beginning of the disk. This is optional.)

If you do everything manually, you can skip the `mbr2gpt` step – use AOMEI to convert the disk to GPT, then repartition, then directly create an EFI System Partition and use a Windows ISO to populate it using `bcdboot`. The disk will now be bootable in UEFI mode.

(The old BCD and BOOTMGR at the root of your C:\ partition can then be deleted – as well as the even older boot.ini and NTLDR if you still have those.)

> Possible thought: I have to set some flags on partitions after converting partition table to GPT to make it bootable, but what would those flags be?

For EFI the boot partition should be formatted as FAT32 and have the correct GPT "partition type GUID". (For example, when using DISKPART, `create part efi` will set the correct type, or `set id=<GUID>` can be used to fix it later.) It sounds like your firmware recognizes NTFS but I wouldn't rely on that.

Additionally, EFI expects the bootloader's exact path to be stored in NVRAM – bcdboot will do that for you if it's being run from an UEFI-booted environment. (bcdboot will *also* install the boot loader at the fallback \efi\boot\bootx64.efi path, so things should work even if it can't update NVRAM for some reason.)

Your problem might not necessarily be with the firmware, though – it might be during the next stage, i.e. the Windows boot manager can't match its BCD configuration to actual partitions. (But again, bcdboot will solve that by generating a brand new `BCD`.)

> Despite MBR partition everything booted up with UEFI without legacy mode on.

This doesn't sound like UEFI mode at all. The "active" flag wouldn't matter in UEFI mode – it's there only for the BIOS boot sector.

> If I just convert MBR to GPT with AOMEI Partition Assistant included in current Hiren's Boot CD while keeping the partitions as the are, Windows becomes unbootable.

That's normal. In BIOS mode, the *boot sector* (which is still there in the MBR sector, even on GPT-partitioned disks) can't proceed because doesn't know how to read GPT partition tables to find the "active" partition.

Whereas in UEFI mode, the firmware can't find any EFI System Partition on the disk that would contain the Windows boot loader in .efi format.

Comment: Thx. This seems to be the right direction.
>This doesn't sound like UEFI mode at all. The "active" flag wouldn't matter in UEFI mode – it's there only for the BIOS boot sector.
It only mattered for being able to shutdown. Also I don't have a `C:\Boot` folder which would be normal on MBR installations folder but `C:\Efi\Microsoft\Boot` with `bootx64.efi` inside and `C:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot` with a lot of files.
And this is definitely on MBR partition table. So I think I have quite an inconsistent state which somehow works.

So I think I'll try direct conversion to GPT and creation of EFI

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense, though I don't know how you ended up with a system like that. (It works when your firmware supports NTFS, but that's something I wouldn't rely on...)

Comment: Indeed, I'll try your way in a few hours. And thx for adding the `/f UEFI` part, I thought I should do this, too. I also did a clean install of Win10 with EFI in VirtualBox to look how everything should look in GParted.
1) 100 MiB fat32 with boot, esp
2) 16 MiB unformatted with msftres
3) Normal Windows partition with msftdata
4) 525 MiB ntfs with hidden, diag

Though CreatePartitions-UEFI.txt suggests 260 MiB for first partition for 4Kn drives and I think any modern SSD should be 4Kn.

Comment: bcdboot will generally autodetect what it should install, so you don't strictly _need_ `/f UEFI` if you're already doing it from an UEFI-booted system and if the disk is EFI-partitioned. I just add it in some situations where I'm not confident that it will guess correctly (i.e. when I'd rather have it fail than end up with a BIOS-mode disk).

Comment: Regarding SSDs, no, even recent ones seem to provide 512-byte logical sectors more often than not. (Meanwhile I think it's possible their "physical" sector size might even 8k or 16k, not just 4k?)

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. As additional measure I had to clean EFI folder on drive C (which didn't work/boot correctly) and somehow also a new EFI folder, that appeared on WinRE partition. Everything boots now perfectly and at this moment Windows 11 is installing itself and is now at 73%.

Answer (score 0):

> My aim is to be able to upgrade to Windows 11.   It was originally a
> Windows XP installation, that went through all the upgrades to
> WinVista, Win7, Win8, Win8.1 and Win10.

The upgrade to Windows 11 may or may not work, depending on the upgrades that took place (clarified during the Q&A).

In addition to having UEFI and Secure Boot, you need TPM V2 and the CPU must be 8th generation or better.

You have said your newest motherboard has TPM 2 so another thing to consider is to back up everything and let Windows 11 create the needed partitions. It knows what to do.

So long as you have the correct partitions, the layout of the SSD is less important.  Partitions beyond the 3 required (UEFI, Recovery, Data) are less important.

Comment: I have a AMD Ryzen 7 5800X, so the CPU is definitely not too old and it's definitely the layout of the SSD that breaks it. I just migrated my installation through all the years to newer computers.

Comment: Anything that will run Windows 11 will not run Windows XP natively (first post)

Comment: Yes, but perhaps I wasn't clean. The original installation of XP was around 2004, I did all the upgrades of Windows inbetween and had several changes of motherboards and CPU.

Comment: Did the motherboard change have the TPM V2 chip?  You have confused the situation by referring to old gear and not saying what you have now.

Comment: Yes, the current motherboard has the TPM v2 chip, it's ASUS Prime B550-Plus.

Answer (score -1):

> The upgrade to Windows 11 will not work.
>
> In addition to having UEFI and Secure Boot, you need TPM V2 and the CPU must be 8th generation or better.

You can bypass the TPM and CPU requirement for an upgrade by setting [AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) in the running system.
But the upgrade will only work if windows already uses GPT and boots UEFI.

However a fresh install is possible with legacy boot if other keys are set in the PE environment during setup:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig]
"BypassTPMCheck"=dword:00000001
"BypassSecureBootCheck"=dword:00000001
"BypassRAMCheck"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that updates will keep functioning after these registry changes have been made. The situation given to us is unworkable for Production Windows 11.

Comment: @John What are the guarantees for new bought stuff a couple years from now? Until proven otherwise I would file that under usual FUD, same as "posready upgrades do not work in XP" and "upgrades from 7 to 10 only possible for a year" etc.

Comment: That confuses the issue. New stuff could not run XP (original question)

Comment: I guess the issue feels okay.

Comment: @xenoson - If the device was running Windows XP it hasn't been a couple of years.  Modern hardware cannot even run Windows 7 natively for a variety of reasons.  Windows XP is more than 2 decades old.

Comment: Who said OP runs ancient hardware? If his hardware runs 7 or 10 fine, 11 will probably run fine as well. TMP and CPU generation are dummy prerequisites. Dropping driver support for less common older stuff is what will show stop it eventually, certainly not CPU performance.

Comment: Just to clear up in this subthread, too: I have modern hardware which qualifies for Win11, just my installation originated from an older computer and thus wasn't partitioned as required by Win11 for upgrade via Windows Update. And the partitioning and fixing for EFI is now complete, Windows 11 is now successfully installed.

Comment: @rarog4k Good job fixing that up. Not too long ago the naysayers would have claimed it is impossible to convert MBR to GPT.

Comment: @xenoson mbr2gpt is part of Windows since 1703, so if I would have had a not inconsistent state of Win10 with 100% conform MBR settings I could have used that. MS actually provided a built-in tool, so nothing is completely impossible.  I remember Win95b, where they also shipped cvt1.exe that converted FAT16 to FAT32 as file system, smaller conversions can definitely be done. :D

Comment: @rarog4k I was just reminded of this particular question https://superuser.com/questions/1416633/can-i-clone-restore-uefi-disk-image-on-legacy-machine-and-boot-the-cloned-resto/1416937 on this site were I was downvoted by some naysayer spreading FUD. Just not fair.